# Parallelogram Angle Relationship Problem

Tags: angle, polygons

**Question:**
If one angle of a parallelogram is $24^{\circ}$ less than twice the smallest angle, then what is the measure of the largest angle of the parallelogram?

**My attempt:**
First of all, I drew a picture.
[image]

Now, there are two choices for selecting the first angle of the parallelogram:

- $\angle A$ (or $\angle C$)
- $\angle B$ (or $\angle D$)

---

**Suppose we start with $\angle A$ (or $\angle C$).**

According to the question,
$$\angle A = 2\angle B - 24^{\circ}$$

Since $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ form co-interior angles, their sum will be $180^\circ$.

$$\begin{align}
&180^\circ - \angle B = 2 \angle B - 24^\circ \\
\implies & 180^\circ + 24^\circ = 3 \angle B \\
\implies &\angle B = \frac{204}{3} = 68^\circ
\end{align}$$
Therefore, the largest angle is $180^\circ - 68^\circ = 112^\circ$.

**If we start with another angle $\angle B$ (Or $\angle D$) we have,**
$$\begin{align}\angle B &= 2\angle B  - 24^\circ \\ \implies \angle B &= 24^\circ \end{align} $$
This result corresponds to the smallest angle.

So the largest angle is $180^\circ - 24^\circ = 156^\circ$

***Therefore the final answer should be $156^\circ$.***

---

Is this correct? According to my book, the answer should be $112^\circ$. It doesn't consider the another case.

Comment: It is assumed that the two angles are different.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I just understood. But it is still confusing because both of the angles are still different - $24^\circ$ and $156^\circ$.

Comment: Do those values satisfy the given criterion?

Comment: Read the first comment